# IndentationError expected an indented block

Tags: python, indentation

Here is the code:

```
def myfirst_yoursecond(p,q):

    a = p.find(" ")
    b = q.find(" ")
    str_p = p[0:a]
    str_q = p[b+1:]

    if str_p == str_q:
           result = True
    else:
        result = False
    return result
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vm_main.py", line 26, in <module>
    import main
  File "/tmp/vmuser_ssgopfskde/main.py", line 22
    result = False
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "IndentationError: expected an indented block"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446366/why-am-i-getting-indentationerror-expected-an-indented-block)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You've mixed tabs and spaces. This can lead to some confusing errors.

I'd suggest using *only* tabs or *only* spaces for indentation.

Using only spaces is generally the easier choice. Most editors have an option for  automatically converting tabs to spaces. If your editor has this option, turn it on.

---

As an aside, your code is more verbose than it needs to be. Instead of this:

```
if str_p == str_q:
    result = True
else:
    result = False
return result
```

Just do this:

```
return str_p == str_q
```

You also appear to have a bug on this line:

```
str_q = p[b+1:]
```

I'll leave you to figure out what the error is.

Comment: Thank you!! It works! Python doesn't support both indentations. It sounds strange.

Comment: It does actually support 8-space tabs, but it's much better to stick to just spaces, particularly if your code moves between editors and systems (which you should expect it to.)

Comment: I'm sorry. I have changed it to q[b+1:]. It's really kind of you to help me a lot.

Comment: I get the same problem about no indent before a def bla(x,y) function line below. Just adding indentation does work. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

This error also occurs if you have a block without any statements in it.

For example:

```
def my_function():
    for i in range(1,10):


def say_hello():
    return "hello"
```

Notice that the `for` block is empty. You can use the [pass](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) statement if you want to test the remaining code in the module.

Comment: I was looking for a statement similar to bash's ':' statement, not easy to formulate a search term for that; came here immediately, and your answer stands out for mentioning a pass stament that I didn't know.  Hence up one. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a Mac and [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) 3, this is what you do.

Go to your `/Packages/User/` and create a file called `Python.sublime-settings` file.

Typically `/Packages/User` is inside your `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Python.sublime-settings` if you are using Mac OS X.

Then you put this in the `Python.sublime-settings`.

```
{
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false
}
```

Credit goes to [Mark Byer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10238788/80353), [Sublime Text 3 documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/indentation.html) and [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

This answer is mostly for readers who had the same issue and stumble upon this and are using Sublime Text 3 on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, and this is what I did to solve the issue.

*Before Indentation:*

[image]

Indentation Error: expected an indented block.

*After indentation:*

[image]

It is working fine. After TAB space.

Answer (score 0):

You should install a editor (or IDE) supporting Python syntax. It can highlight source code and make basic format checking.
For example: [Eric 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_(software)), [Spyder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_%28software%29), Ninjia, or [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs), [Vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi).

Comment: I user Pyscripter in windows. Because I have to do other jobs in windows although I'm really fond of using linux.

Comment: Re *Ninjia*: Do you mean *[NINJA-IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninja-IDE)*?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 10 years ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can chime in?