# Invalid Syntax in Python 3 when creating a list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a list of tuples and I am getting Invalid Syntax:

```
def match_enzymes(strand, enzymes, sequences):
'''(str, list of str, list of str) -> list of (str, list of int) tuples

Return a list of tuples where the first item of each tuple is the name of a restriction enzyme and the second item is the list of indices of the restriction sites that the enzyme cuts.

>>>
>>>
>>>
'''

list_of_tuples = []

for i in range(len(enzymes)):
    list_of_tuples.append((enzymes[i], restriction_sites(strand, sequence[i]))

return list_of_tuples
```

Comment: If your code is indented like this, you would get invalid syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Expected an indented block" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657576/expected-an-indented-block-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two problems:

1) you are missing the closing parentheses in:

```
 list_of_tuples.append((enzymes[i], restriction_sites(strand, sequence[i])) #<--!!!
```

2) your code is not indented  currently