# Using MyClass(object) gone wrong?

Tags: python, function, class, init

```
class Myclass(object):
    def __init__(self , msg , integer):
    self.msg = msg
    self.integer = integer
    print (self.msg)
    print (self.integer)
    return
```

Error

```
File "<input>", line 3
    self.msg = msg
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: DUP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446366/why-am-i-getting-indentationerror-expected-an-indented-block

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate, and fyi Python2 allows mixed usage of tabs and spaces but Python3 does not. It recommends using spaces for uniformity.
Please check PEP8 for more info:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

EDIT:
And please indent after defining a function. It must be all indented up to  the code block.

Comment: He didn't even indent after `def` :joy:

Comment: @T.Woody O man.. I did not even see that that's on me.

Comment: I won't be upset as long as your smiling with me ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Myclass(object):
    def __init__(self , msg , integer):
        self.msg = msg
        self.integer = integer
        print (self.msg)
        print (self.integer)
        return
```

Whitespace matters in python.

Edit: Ran without issues

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...  def __init__(self, msg, integer):
...   self.msg=msg
...   self.integer = integer
...   print(self.msg)
... 
>>> x = MyClass('foo', 5)
foo
```

Comment: it dind't work so strange :/

Comment: @m0m0c4t what did you try and what is the error message?

Comment: File "<input>", line 3
    self . msg = msg
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: still same error @T.Woody

Comment: @m0m0c4t I just tested the code in terminal, for an output to put here. Please try the same, and get back to me...

Comment: I solved the problem I'm new in coding but I tried this and did work: def __init__(self,msg,integer) #not: .../(self , msg , integer)

Comment: @m0m0c4t I can assure you that spaces in your parameter block would not change anything when the code is compiled.

Comment: I use python 3.7 and pycharm for IDE and in pyCahrm spaces in matters cause the program can not identify the lib sometimes I don't know why but it works like that sounds ridiculous Im new in coding but I'm researching whole day it must not be like this but it happens..

Comment: @m0m0c4t I am sorry, but that is not the case. Things do not just decide to act a certain way sometimes and we can't figure it out. I am not new and coding, and I am informing you: That is not how it works.

Comment: I got it ; thank you for helping me and I'm sorry that if I bothered you ^^