# expected an indented block Python script compress

Tags: python, zip, compression

I have problem about my code in below, help me please for correct my code

```py
import glob 
import os 
import shutil from zipfile 
import ZipFile from os 
import path from shutil 
import make_archive

def main():
    list_of_files = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\RezaPal\\Desktop\\test compress\\.docx')
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    # Check if file exists
        if path.exists(latest_file):
    # get the path to the file in the current directory
        src = path.realpath(latest_file);
    # rename the original file
        #os.rename("backup_filetest.docx","filetest.docx")
    # now put things into a ZIP archive
        #root_dir,tail = path.split(src)
        #shutil.make_archive("guru99 archive", "zip", root_dir)
    # more fine-grained control over ZIP files
        with ZipFile("backup_filetest.zip","w") as newzip:
        newzip.write("filetest.docx")
            newzip.write("filetest.docx.bak")

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Indentation is extremely important in Python. Yours is incorrect. https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Comment: You need to format the code properly. Blocks should be indented with either 4 spaces, or tabs (don't use both)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "IndentationError: expected an indented block"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446366/why-am-i-getting-indentationerror-expected-an-indented-block)

Answer (score -1):

Correct code:

```py
def main():
    list_of_files = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\RezaPal\\Desktop\\test compress\\.docx')
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    # Check if file exists
    if path.exists(latest_file):
    # get the path to the file in the current directory
        src = path.realpath(latest_file);
    # rename the original file
        #os.rename("backup_filetest.docx","filetest.docx")
    # now put things into a ZIP archive
        #root_dir,tail = path.split(src)
        #shutil.make_archive("guru99 archive", "zip", root_dir)
    # more fine-grained control over ZIP files
    with ZipFile("backup_filetest.zip","w") as newzip:
        newzip.write("filetest.docx")
        newzip.write("filetest.docx.bak")


if __name__== "__main__":
      main()
```

I don't know how the "whith"-block should be executed: with a condition or not. Consider this point.