# What is the reason for an IndentationError in my code?

Tags: python

i have python code like this, basically i just want to solve this product percentage so the result in product percentage will appear, here's the code:

```py
product_a_sales = 5
product_b_sales = 5
total_sales = product_b_sales - product_a_sales
try:
product_a_percentage_sales=(product_a_sales/total_sales) * 100
except ZeroDivisionError:
    product_a_percentage_sales=0
```

and it returns an error like this

```
 File "<ipython-input-30-aa369d387f3d>", line 5
    product_a_percentage_sales=(product_a_sales/total_sales) * 100
                             ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "IndentationError: expected an indented block"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446366/why-am-i-getting-indentationerror-expected-an-indented-block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic syntax error.

The statements between `try` and `except` must be indented.

The error message actually explains it perfectly: the line with `product_a_percentage_sales =` is not an "indented block", but an indented block was expected.

Refer to the Python tutorial for more information: [8. Handling Errors](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

You have to just watch your whitespace and indentations on the code after try:

```
    product_a_sales = 5
    product_b_sales = 5
    total_sales = product_b_sales - product_a_sales
    try:
        product_a_percentage_sales=(product_a_sales/total_sales) * 100
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        product_a_percentage_sales=0
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Error message explains, in line 5, you have [syntax error related to incorrect indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndentationError). Frome more info on indentation in Python, please refer to these links: [1](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html), [2](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation), [3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-in-python/) and [4](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp).

The correct syntax would be as follows:

```
product_a_sales = 5
product_b_sales = 5
total_sales = product_b_sales - product_a_sales
try:
    product_a_percentage_sales=(product_a_sales/total_sales) * 100
except ZeroDivisionError:
    product_a_percentage_sales=0
```