# How to use "pass" statement?

Tags: python, statements

I am in the process of learning Python and I have reached the section about the `pass` statement. The guide I'm using defines it as being a null statement that is commonly used as a placeholder.

I still don't fully understand what that means though. What would be a simple/basic situation where the `pass` statement would be used and why would it be needed?

Comment: I have never needed to do this in real life, but I could suppose `pass` would be useful when you want to override a method in a subclass to do nothing.

Comment: @kojiro e.g. sometimes useful when doing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_(computer_programming)

Comment: Very handy when processing exceptions. Sometimes an exception means a normal condition that just requires a different type of processing. In that case `pass` in the `except` block comes in very handy.

Answer (score 513, accepted):

Suppose you are designing a new class with some methods that you don't want to implement, yet.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def meth_a(self):
        pass

    def meth_b(self):
        print "I'm meth_b"
```

If you were to leave out the `pass`, the code wouldn't run.

You would then get an:

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

To summarize, the `pass` statement does nothing particular, but it can act as a placeholder, as demonstrated here.

Comment: Ok, after reading your response I think i understand. I definitely see how it is handy as a temporary placeholder now.

Comment: Well, in this case one could also use `return`, though with a slight loss of clarity.

Comment: @delnan: agree. In this case, return would also do the job but as you said, it would be less explicit.

Comment: I really don't think this properly answers the question. Citing one possible use for something, even if it is the most common use for it, is not the same as explaining what it is for.

Comment: @Schilcote: I see your point. I added another short explanation to my initial answer. However, I think that a simple example often helps to understand a certain concept.

Comment: Nice explanations. Would it be correct to say that "pass" is equivalent to "{ }" in say C#?

Comment: Yes, as you said @petern .

Comment: The answer by @Anaphory, below, shows why this is important language element.

Comment: At this point I know little of Python, but it seems analogous to Ruby's "skip" which is often used in unit testing to skip tests one does not want run.

Comment: This explains one use of `pass`, but I still don't really understand what it does. 
 Is there a use for this in production code?  From your example, I would opt to just not add that method until I'm ready to implement it, or I would simply do `return`.

Comment: I would prefer `raise NotImplementedError` over `pass`

Answer (score 258):

Python has the syntactical requirement that code blocks (after `if`, `except`, `def`, `class` etc.) cannot be empty. Empty code blocks are however useful in a variety of different contexts, such as in examples below, which are the most frequent use cases I have seen.

Therefore, if nothing is supposed to happen in a code block, a `pass` is needed for such a block to not produce an `IndentationError`. Alternatively, any statement (including just a term to be evaluated, like the `Ellipsis` literal `...` or a string, most often a docstring) can be used, but the `pass` makes clear that indeed nothing is supposed to happen, and does not need to be actually evaluated and (at least temporarily) stored in memory.

- Ignoring (all or) a certain type of `Exception` (example from `xml`):

  ```
   try:
       self.version = "Expat %d.%d.%d" % expat.version_info
   except AttributeError:
       pass # unknown
  ```

  **Note:** Ignoring all types of raises, as in the following example from `pandas`, is generally considered bad practice, because it also catches exceptions that should probably be passed on to the caller, e.g. `KeyboardInterrupt` or `SystemExit` (or even `HardwareIsOnFireError` – How do you  know you aren't running on a custom box with specific errors defined, which some calling application would want to know about?).

  ```
   try:
       os.unlink(filename_larry)
   except:
       pass
  ```

  Instead using at least `except Error:` or in this case preferably `except OSError:` is considered much better practice. A quick analysis of all Python modules I have installed gave me that more than 10% of all `except ...: pass` statements catch all exceptions, so it's still a frequent pattern in Python programming.
- Deriving an exception class that does not add new behaviour (e.g., in [SciPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy)):

  ```
   class CompileError(Exception):
       pass
  ```

  Similarly, classes intended as abstract base class often have an explicit empty `__init__` or other methods that subclasses are supposed to derive (e.g., `pebl`):

  ```
   class _BaseSubmittingController(_BaseController):
       def submit(self, tasks): pass
       def retrieve(self, deferred_results): pass
  ```
- Testing that code runs properly for a few test values, without caring about the results (from `mpmath`):

  ```
   for x, error in MDNewton(mp, f, (1,-2), verbose=0,
                            norm=lambda x: norm(x, inf)):
       pass
  ```
- In class or function definitions, often a docstring is already in place as the *obligatory statement* to be executed as the only thing in the block. In such cases, the block may contain `pass` *in addition* to the docstring in order to say “This is indeed intended to do nothing.”, for example in `pebl`:

  ```
   class ParsingError(Exception):
       """Error encountered while parsing an ill-formed datafile."""
       pass
  ```
- In some cases, `pass` is used as a placeholder to say “This method/class/if-block/... has not been implemented yet, but this will be the place to do it”, although I personally prefer the `Ellipsis` literal `...` in order to strictly differentiate between this and the intentional “no-op” in the previous example. (**Note that the Ellipsis literal is a valid expression only in Python 3**)

  For example, if I write a model in broad strokes, I might write

  ```
   def update_agent(agent):
       ...
  ```

  where others might have

  ```
   def update_agent(agent):
       pass
  ```

  before

  ```
   def time_step(agents):
       for agent in agents:
           update_agent(agent)
  ```

  as a reminder to fill in the `update_agent` function at a later point, but run some tests already to see if the rest of the code behaves as intended. (A third option for this case is `raise NotImplementedError`. This is useful in particular for two cases: Either *“This abstract method should be implemented by every subclass, and there isn't a generic way to define it in this base class”*, or *“This function, with this name, is not yet implemented in this release, but this is what its signature will look like”*)

Comment: Breadcrumb trail to follow regarding `Ellipsis` https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-January/011793.html

Answer (score 25):

Besides its use as a placeholder for unimplemented functions, `pass` can be useful in filling out an if-else statement ("Explicit is better than implicit.")

```
def some_silly_transform(n):
    # Even numbers should be divided by 2
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n /= 2
        flag = True
    # Negative odd numbers should return their absolute value
    elif n < 0:
        n = -n
        flag = True
    # Otherwise, number should remain unchanged
    else:
        pass
```

Of course, in this case, one would probably use `return` instead of assignment, but in cases where mutation is desired, this works best.

The use of `pass` here is especially useful to warn future maintainers (including yourself!) not to put redundant steps outside of the conditional statements. In the example above, `flag` is set in the two specifically mentioned cases, but not in the `else`-case. Without using `pass`, a future programmer might move `flag = True` to outside the condition—thus setting `flag` in *all* cases.

---

Another case is with the boilerplate function often seen at the bottom of a file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

In some files, it might be nice to leave that there with `pass` to allow for easier editing later, and to make explicit that nothing is expected to happen when the file is run on its own.

---

Finally, as mentioned in other answers, it can be useful to do nothing when an exception is caught:

```
try:
    n[i] = 0
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Comment: I think the first two examples are generally bad practice. Regarding the first example, you should set `flag = False` before the `if ... elif ` block in order to prevent obscure "NameError: name 'flag' is not defined" errors later on. Regarding the second example, it seems bizzar to have to add `if __name__ == "__main__":     pass` to the majority of Python files which do not do anythng when executed directly (which is the case when you are writing modular code). With Python >= 3.0, you should use `...` (Ellipsis) instead of `pass` to indicate "finish later" blocks.

Comment: If all the else clause does it pass, i.e. does nothing, then why even bother to include it at all?

Comment: @Junglemath You might want to make it clear to later developers that there are other conditions that need to be filled out, other than the ones enumerated. In general, explicit is better than implicit, and this is a way of explicitly saying "I haven't listed all the conditions; there are others, for which the current functionality is to do nothing, though that may not always be the case."

Answer (score 21):

The best and most accurate way to think of `pass` is as a way to explicitly tell the interpreter to do nothing. In the same way the following code:

```
def foo(x,y):
    return x+y
```

means "if I call the function foo(x, y), sum the two numbers the labels x and y represent and hand back the result",

```
def bar():
    pass
```

means "If I call the function bar(), do absolutely nothing."

The other answers are quite correct, but it's also useful for a few things that don't involve place-holding.

For example, in a bit of code I worked on just recently, it was necessary to divide two variables, and it was possible for the divisor to be zero.

```
c = a / b
```

will, obviously, produce a ZeroDivisionError if b is zero. In this particular situation, leaving c as zero was the desired behavior in the case that b was zero, so I used the following code:

```
try:
    c = a / b
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
```

Another, less standard usage is as a handy place to put a breakpoint for your debugger. For example, I wanted a bit of code to break into the debugger on the 20th iteration of a for... in statement. So:

```
for t in range(25):
    do_a_thing(t)
    if t == 20:
        pass
```

with the breakpoint on pass.

Comment: `def bar(): pass` doesn't do "absolutely nothing". It still returns `None`, implicitly.

Comment: Your point regarding the debugger is often overlooked but an important one. +1

Answer (score 11):

A common use case where it can be used 'as is' is to override a class just to create a type (which is otherwise the same as the superclass), e.g.

```
class Error(Exception):
    pass
```

So you can raise and catch `Error` exceptions. What matters here is the type of exception, rather than the content.

Answer (score 9):

You can say that **pass** means a **NOP** (no operation) operation. You will get a clear picture after this example:

**C Program**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int age = 12;
  
    if( age < 18 )
    {
         printf("You are not adult, so you can't do that task ");
    }
    else if( age >= 18 && age < 60)
    {
        // I will add more code later inside it 
    }
    else
    {
         printf("You are too old to do anything , sorry ");
    }
}
```

Now how you will write that in Python:

```
age = 12

if age < 18:

    print "You are not adult, so you can't do that task"

elif age >= 18 and age < 60:

else:

    print "You are too old to do anything , sorry "
```

But your code will give an error because it required an indented block after **elif**. Here is the role of the **pass** keyword.

```
age = 12

if age < 18:

    print "You are not adult, so you can't do that task"

elif age >= 18 and age < 60:
    
    pass

else:

    print "You are too old to do anything , sorry "
```

Now I think it's clear to you.

Answer (score 8):

`pass` in Python basically does nothing, but unlike a comment it is not ignored by interpreter. So you can take advantage of it in a lot of places by making it a place holder:

1: Can be used in class

```
class TestClass:
    pass
```

2: Can be use in loop and conditional statements:

```
if (something == true):  # used in conditional statement
    pass

while (some condition is true):  # user is not sure about the body of the loop
    pass
```

3: Can be used in function:

```
def testFunction(args): # The programmer wants to implement the body of the function later
    pass
```

`pass` is mostly used when the programmer does not want to give implementation at the moment, but still wants to create a certain class/function/conditional statement which can be used later on. Since the Python interpreter does not allow for a blank or unimplemented class, function, or conditional statement it gives an error:

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

`pass` can be used in such scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I think the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) describe it quite well and provide some examples:

> The *pass* statement does nothing. It can be used when a statement is required syntactically but the program requires no action. For example:
>
> `>>> while True:
>   ...     pass  # Busy-wait for keyboard interrupt (Ctrl+C)
>   ...`
>
> This is commonly used for creating minimal classes:
>
> `>>> class MyEmptyClass:
>   ...     pass
>   ...`
>
> Another place *pass* can be used is as a place-holder for a function or conditional body when you are working on new code, allowing you to keep thinking at a more abstract level. The *pass* is silently ignored:
>
> `>>> def initlog(*args):
>   ...     pass   # Remember to implement this!
>   ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import a module, if it exists, and ignore importing it, if that module does not exists, you can use the below code:

```
try:
    import a_module
except ImportError:
    pass
# The rest of your code
```

If you avoid writing the *pass* statement and continue writing the rest of your code, a IndentationError would be raised, since the lines after opening the except block are not indented.

Answer (score 0):

As the book said, I only ever use it as a temporary placeholder, i.e.,

```
# code that does something to to a variable, var
if var == 2000:
    pass
else:
    var += 1
```

And then later fill in the scenario where `var == 2000`.

Comment: what book are you talking about?

Comment: sorry... guide, that the OP mentions

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the "main" use of "I don't want anything to go here," here's one I just found, assuming `gen` is an `Iterator`:

```py
i = 0
obj = None

for i, obj in enumerate(gen):
    pass
```

This gets the last object `yield`ed from `gen` and the length of `gen`, all in one pass. (Sorta similar to a `while` loop that ends with a semicolon in C, come to think of it.)

Answer (score 0):

**Pass** is usually helpful when you are writing code to design a game or something of that type , now as you proceed with the code , you would realize that , there are some functions you don't want to move ahead and want to leave it untouched and move further on with the code and then revisit the function later , but as you do so , the compiler would obviously thrown an error saying it isn't either recognized and all sorts of other things!! In this condition you use **pass** so that the compiler would simply neglect the function and move further on with the code !!

For example -

```
if __name__ = "__main__":
pass
print("Hello World!")
```

Here the compiler would neglect the if name part and would print Hello World as directed !!

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to write a block, like this:

```py
if statement:
    pass
for i in range(abc):
    pass
def func():
    pass
```

And `pass` can to be a placeholder.

Second, it can let you 'communicate' with IDE:
When you want to let your IDE decrement indentations like this:
If your program written here:

```
class abc(parent):
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params=params
        if d:
            return
        else:
            return
        # cursor in there
```

Now your indentations count is 2, but you want it is 1 in next line.
You can type a `pass`, and your program to be this:

```
class abc(parent):
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params=params
        if d:
            return
        else:
            return
        pass# cursor in there
```

And return. It will let you happy:

```
class abc(parent):
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params=params
        if d:
            return
        else:
            return
        pass
    # cursor in there
```

Now the indentation count is 1.

Answer (score 0):

[**pass**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) is just the indication code of **emptiness**.

For example, `pass` is used to create a empty class or function as shown below:

```py
class Test:
    pass

def test():
    pass
```

But, if a class or function really doesn't have anything even `pass` as shown below:

```py
class Test:
    # pass

def test():
    # psss
```

There is an error as shown below:

> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

And as I said before, `pass` is just the indication code of **emptiness** so if there is some code after `pass`, the code works as shown below:

```py
class Test:
    pass
    x = "Hello World"

def test():
    pass
    return "Hello World"

print(Test.x) # Hello World
print(test()) # Hello World
```

Answer (score -1):

The pass statement in Python is used when a statement is required syntactically, but you do not want any command or code to execute.

The pass statement is a null operation; nothing happens when it executes. The pass is also useful in places where your code will eventually go, but has not been written yet (e.g., in stubs for example):

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

for letter in 'Python':
   if letter == 'h':
      pass
      print 'This is pass block'
   print 'Current Letter :', letter

print "Good bye!"
```

This will produce the following result:

```
Current Letter : P
Current Letter : y
Current Letter : t
This is pass block
Current Letter : h
Current Letter : o
Current Letter : n
Good bye!
```

The preceding code does not execute any statement or code if the value of letter is 'h'. The pass statement is helpful when you have created a code block, but it is no longer required.

You can then remove the statements inside the block, but let the block remain with a pass statement so that it doesn't interfere with other parts of the code.

Answer (score -1):

Pass refers to ignore...as simple as it is. If the given condition is true and the next statement is *pass*, it ignores that value or iteration and proceed to the next line.

Example:

```
for i in range (1, 100):
    if i%2 == 0:
        pass
    else:
        print(i)
```

Output: Prints all the odd numbers from 1-100

This is because the modulus of an even number is equal to zero, hence it ignores the number and proceeds to next number. Since odd numbers' modulus are not equal to zero, the *else* part of the loop is executed and it's printed.

Comment: I get a `SyntaxError`. Also, this is not a good use of `pass` because you could simply do `for i in range(1,100):print(i)if i%2else""`

Comment: Yes, as you said it isn't good practice but I just wanted to give a example that is easy to understand.

Comment: I see why you got a syntax error, it is because my code was edited mistakenly.

Comment: My apologies for that, will fix it.

Answer (score -2):

pass is used to avoid indentation errors in Python.

If we take languages like C, C++, and Java, they have braces like:

```
 if(i==0)
 {}
 else
 {//some code}
```

But in Python we use indentation instead of braces, so to avoid such errors we use *pass*.

Remembered as you were playing a quiz and

```
if(dont_know_the_answer)
    pass
```

Example program,

```
for letter in 'geeksforgeeks':
    pass
print 'Last letter: ', letter
```