# Use of "Pass" keyword in Python

Tags: python, keyword

What is the use of the "pass" keyword in Python? I don't know why or in what instance you would need to use it, since it literally does nothing. Can anyone give me a reason to use these other than for testing? It serves as a good placeholder, true, but does it have any other uses?

Comment: This has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886168/how-to-use-the-pass-statement-in-python). Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22612774/6009280) in particular.

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can use `pass` as placeholder for code, which you want to write later and syntactically you need some statement there.