# Exit program without triggering exception handling

Tags: python, exception

I wasn't really sure how to title my question, but my issue is this; I have my program set up to guess a number and handle exceptions. The program loops until the number is guessed, but when the program exits, my exception message shows at the same time. How can I fix this?

```
num = None
while num != 31:
    try:
        num = int(input("What is the age of my creator? \n"))
        if num < 31:
            print("Higher! Guess again! \n")
        elif num > 31:
            print("Lower! Guess again! \n")
        elif num == 31:
            print("Good Guess!")
            exit()
    except:
        print("Numbers only! \n")
```

This is my output:

What is the age of my creator?
31
Good Guess!
Numbers only!

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the exception message, I would recommend a `break` instead of `exit`, for a more natural exit from your program. Try this:

```
try:
    ...
    elif num == 31:
        print("Good Guess!")
        break
except ValueError:
    print("Numbers only! \n")
```

Also, you should catch a specific error rather than a catch-all bare `except`.

---

If you want to silence any error messages, you should use [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) instead. From the docs:

> The `pass` statement does nothing. It can be used when a statement is
>   required syntactically but the program requires no action.

```
try:
    ...
except ValueError:
    pass
```

`pass` is an innocuous placeholder statement that does nothing.

---

- [How To Use The Pass Statement In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886168/how-to-use-the-pass-statement-in-python)

Comment: I tried it.  It changes nothing.  This is my output:

What is the age of my creator? 
31
Good Guess!
Numbers only! 


Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @OrphaMortimer 1. No print statement after pass. 2. Save your file.

Comment: Also, I recommend break inside `try`, rather than exit.

Comment: I removed the print statement.  The output looks better, but how could I do the same while keeping the exception print statement?

Comment: @OrphaMortimer Like I said, use a `break` instead of `exit`.

Comment: ahhh!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @OrphaMortimer Also avoid using plain `except:` and use a more specific one like `except ValueError:` in your case

Comment: Thanks, added that in.