# Is there an equivalent of Python's pass statement in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I would like to know if there is an equivalent of Python's pass statement in VBA.

I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: From what I can see; no there isn't. You can block comment code or use a GoTo to bypass code but I'm not aware of a null placeholder. What context did you want to use it under?

Comment: @ Flephal, for placing a breakpoint.

Comment: You could perhaps use DoEvents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of `Stop` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46112528/6535336)) seems to be the best thing to do if you are looking for some "non-statement" that you can use to insert a breakpoint, because the `Stop` command causes the code to break when it is reached, i.e. you don't even need to mark it as a breakpoint because it **is** one.

You might also like to consider using `Debug.Assert some_logical_expression`, which will break automatically whenever the logical expression evaluates to `False`.  So `Debug.Assert False` would be equivalent to `Stop`, and `Debug.Assert x = 3` would be equivalent to `If x <> 3 Then Stop`.

Answer (score 5):

In Python [you need the `Pass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886168/how-to-use-the-pass-statement-in-python), because otherwise the methods will not run.
In VBA, its perfectly ok if you leave an empty method like this:

```
Public Function Foo() As String()
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

Maby you are looking for the "Stop" statement.
The good thing about it is that it doesn't clear your variables.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what are you trying to achieve.

You may declare a Label and then use GoTo Label e.g. declare a label (like **Skip:**)in your code where you want to jump if a condition is met and then use GoTo Skip

Below is the small demo code to give you an idea about this...

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 10
    If i = 5 Then GoTo Skip
    MsgBox i
Next i
Skip:
```