# Can you help me fix an error with python while loop

Tags: python, indentation

This is the code

```
GrassFilledX = GrassGenX
GrassFilledY = GrassGenY

GrassFillL = True

while GrassFillL == True:
    if gx == hgx or hgx2:



while not crashed:
```

The error says

```
while not crashed:
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Answer (score 1):

Python expects an indented block after an `if` statement.

If you want an empty block, use `pass`:

```
while GrassFillL == True:
    if gx == hgx or hgx2:
        pass

while not crashed:
```

This has the same effect in other languages as an empty pair of braces, like `if(condition){}`. In Python you're not allowed to leave a block empty, you must at least have an NOP statement, the `pass`, in the block, to make the program valid.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13886195/5958455) is a similar (yet essentially the same) use case of `pass`.

Comment: continue, would also work. But there is one difference, pass will do nothing and continue will skip the current iteration to next iteration. I don't know what he really wants, just info.