# Is the 'pass' statement necessary for custom assertions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider:

```
class MyCleanUpError(Exception):
    """Error raised during teardown."""
    pass
```

versus:

```
class MyCleanUpError(Exception):
    """Error raised during teardown."""
```

I've seen the class declared with and with out the `pass` statement. Which is appropriate?

Comment: The pass statement would be needed if you did not have the doc string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the pass statement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886168/how-to-use-the-pass-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

the `pass` statement simply does nothing. since `"""whatever this string is"""` is a valid object, it is fine without the pass statement. you can also use `...` (`Ellipsis`) in python 3 +, or `1`, or `None` or whatever you want to do.
you just cant do this:

```
class MyCleanUpError(Exception):
```

`# other code`

or else you will get an `IndentationError`.
you also cant use a comment as a placeholder.
it is generally appropriate to use `pass` or `...`, because they make more sense than `1` or just having a docstring.