# Role of pass statement inside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie in object oriented programming. After defining a class we simply create objects and try to access different variables and functions inside the class. In the following code I want to know that why we again have to mention class Dataset inside the function ans secondly what is the role of pass statement?

```
def read_data_set():
    class Dataset:
        pass
    data_sets = Dataset()
    return(data_sets)
    #Function call
x=read_data_set()
print(x)
```

Comment: "Why we have to mention it again"…?! In one step you're *defining* the `class Dataset`, in the next step you're *instantiating* it. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to define a class inside a function BTW. This looks like pretty bad sample code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886168/how-to-use-the-pass-statement-in-python

Comment: I haven't mentioned whole code. I define class Dataset consisting of several variables and functions and then I define a function read_data_set that is calling calss Dataset. I am just trying to understand this piece of code. Why it is a bad practice?

Comment: A class should only be defined once. By putting it inside a function, you're redefining it every time you call the function. Sometimes there can be a use for that, but usually it's just unnecessary work being done every time you call the function. – I understand why you might ask about `pass`, but I don't understand what is unclear about the rest of the code. Can you clarify what you don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

It basically does nothing.

It is often used as a placeholder like in your code; you'll notice that the code does not run at all without the `pass` there.

```py
class SomeClass:
    pass # to be filled
```

This is because Python expects something to be under the definition of `SomeClass`, but being empty it raises an `IndentationError`.

```py
class SomeClass:
    # to be filled <--- empty
other_function() # <--- IndentationError
```

It is also used with `try`-`except` when you do not want to do anything:

```py
try:
    some_stuff()
except SomeException:
    pass # I don't mind this
```

Comment: So, if it does nothing, why is it *needed*?

Comment: I mentioned that there are cases where it is used as a placeholder and the code won't run at all otherwise.

Comment: *Why* won't it run otherwise if `pass` does nothing?

Comment: I added details regarding `IndentationError`.

Answer (score 2):

`pass` does nothing, it just makes Python indentations correct.

---

Let's say you want to create an empty function, sth like:

```py
def empty_func():

empty_func()  # throws IndentationError
```

Let's try to put a comment inside:

```
def empty_func_with_comment():
    # empty

empty_func_with_comment()  # throws IndentationError
```

To make it work we need to fix indentations by using pass:

```
def empty_func_with_pass():
    pass

empty_func_with_pass()  # it works
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why do we mention class Dataset inside the function twice?**

The first time

```
class Dataset:
    pass
```

the class is defined,

and the second one:

```
data_sets = Dataset()
```

an instance of this class (an object) is created. Exactly as the OP has written:

> After defining a class we simply create objects.

Since `class` is just a python statement it can be used anywhere: including function bodies, like in this case. So here the class is defined each time the function `read_data_set()` is called and is not defined at all if it is not called.

---

**What is the role of pass statement?**

In this example

```
class Dataset:
    pass
```

the `pass` statement means defining a class with no members added inside it. It means that the class and its objects contain only some "default" functions and variables (aka methods and fields) that are derived from `object` by any class.

---

In general `pass` is used when you introduce a new block and want to leave it empty:

```
expression:
    pass
```

You must include at least one instruction inside a block, that's why sometimes you need `pass` to say that you don't want to do anything inside the block. It is true for functions:

```
def do_nothing():
    pass  # function that does nothing
```

loops:

```
for i in collection:  # just walk through the collection
    pass              # but do nothing at each iteration
```

exception handling:

```
try:
    do_something()
except SomeException:
    pass    #  silently ignore SomeException
```

context managers:

```
with open(filename):    # open a file but do nothing with it
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The pass statement means that you initialise your class without defining a constructor or any attributes. Try ommitting it : The error that you see is due to the fact that python will expect the following line to belong to your class - and will consider that the indentation used is not correct.

Regarding the fact that your class name is called again inside your function : it means that you are instanciating the class you just defined. Thus, what your function returns is an object of your class.

Comment: So it means that if I want to create some object inside a function( that is defined outside the class) ,First I have to  again define that class with a pass statement and after that I can call constructors

Comment: Why class intialization is compulsory? I run the above code omitting class Dataset and pass statement it still works fine

Comment: @user Because you have defined the class somewhere else before? Then yeah, redefining it is pretty superfluous and counter productive.

Comment: @user10163680 If your class was declared before you call the function where you want to use it, than you don't need to redefine the class with `pass`. You might wan't to define a class inside a function only if it was not defined yet or if you wan't to change the definition.

Comment: I have to creat the objects of class inside read_data_set function. It is compulsory to redefine it with pass statement

Comment: If your class is already defined, redefining it will annulate previous definition for the scope of your function. So the object that your function returns has none of the attributes / methods of the definition outside your function