# Are the iteration step and the iteration pass the same in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure what a **iteration step** precisely is.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Computing) gives this explanation about iteration

> Iteration in computing is the technique marking out of a block of statements within a computer program for a defined number of repetitions. That block of statements is said to be iterated; a computer scientist might also refer to that block of statements as an "iteration".

The python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) says

> The for statement in Python differs a bit from what you may be used to in C or Pascal. Rather than always iterating over an arithmetic progression of numbers (like in Pascal), or giving the user the ability to define both the iteration step and halting condition (as C) ...

Consider this example

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i;
   for (i=1; i<=3; i++)
   {
       printf("%d\n", i);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

It is obvious that the total number of steps is equal to 3.

accordingly, the total number of steps is equal to 3 in the following code.

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in mylist:
...    print(i**2)
```

this code print an i^2 at one iteration step, one iteration step is also called a iteration pass.

Is my understanding right?

Comment: *Python* *for* loop is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop.

Comment: _It is obvious that the iteration step is equal to 3_ no, the step is 1 in your C code: your are doing `i++`, which is the same as `i += 1` in this context, not as `i += 3`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the iteration step is the third part of the `for` loop. In your example, it's `i++`. That code increments the value by one each time you go through the loop. Python doesn't have an equivalent concept baked into its `for` loops, because they iterate over iterable objects which are responsible for generating their own values however they want. Not all iterable objects have a meaningful concept of an iteration step in the C style.

That said, the most direct analogy to a classic C-style `for` loop in Python is a `for` loop on a `range` object. The `range` object *does* have a `step`, though it defaults to `1` and so you may not always see it specified explicitly. A needlessly verbose translation of your C loop to Python would be:

```
for i in range(1, 4, 1): # the 1 last 1 could be omitted, since it's the default
    ...
```

The iteration gives values to `i` starting at `1` on the first iteration (from the first `1` passed to range). It stops when the value would become (or passes) `4` (equivalent to the `<= 3` condition in the C loop). The iteration step is `1`, equivalent to `i++`.

Specifying the step is more useful when you're doing other odd kinds of looping, like counting down the even values from ten to zero:

```
for i in range(10, -1, -2): # 10, 8, 6, ..., 0
    ...
```

In C that would be:

```
for (i = 10; i > -1; i -= 2) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **step** isn't an iteration concept in contrast of **pass**, it is related to a **counter**.

In your **C** example, the `i` is a counter. The starting value of the counter is `1`. The **step** equals to `1` too. The **halting condition** says "if the counter is less or equal `3` - end loop". In this case the code inside `for` loop will be passed 3 times. Or by another words, it will have 3 iteration (repetition).

Take another case: `for (i = 0; i <= 15; i = i + 3)`. Here, the **step** equals to `3`, but the number of **passes** equals to `5`. If the **step** will be `5`, the number of **passes** will decrease and will be equal to `3`.

So, the **step** is how fast the **counter** grows or decreases. The number of **passes** are resulting value, dependent from: counter, step, halting condition. Bear in mind, that each pass can be last, due to `break`, `return` statements or due to a run-time error.

The same logic can be applied to **Python**.

```
start = 0
end = 16
step = 3
for i in range(start, end, step):
    pass
```

Note the `pass` statement? It fits especially well to your question.
Information about the `pass`: [How to use the pass statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13886168/2913477)

But in spite the same logic can be applied to **Python**, the `for` loop works in totally different way under the hood. If you interested, I advise you to watch [CPython internals - Iterators - Lecture 7](https://youtu.be/8-KfIsDbxVY).

Now, consider your **Python's** example:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in mylist:
...    print(i**2)
```

The `mylist` is a sequence object and it has iterator object, which knows as this sequence should be processed. If you watch the video I gave above, you will understand what I am talking about.

Some iterator objects hides and maintains `start`, `stop`, `step` variables itself. There are others, that uses another data structures, linked list for example. They are determining the amount of iterations by another way. The passes haven’t gone anywhere though, the loop is repeated `3` times here, because `mylist` iterator returns `3` items.

**Conclusion:** No, the pass and step are different things in **Python** as well as in **C**. The step size determines the number of passes.