# What is the equivalent of 'pass' from Python?

Tags: rust

I want to check if the result from a request is having any issue. I categorize it into two: i) server error, ii) something else that is not a success. The third category is, result actually being a success. However, in the third category, I don't want to do anything.

So, my desirable code is:

```
if res.status().is_server_error() {
        panic!("server error!");
    } else if !(res.status.is_success()){
        panic!("Something else happened. Status: {:?}", res.status());
    } else{
        pass;
    }
```

I am aware of other ways to achieve this result: using `match`, `if`s instead of `if else if`. But I wanted to learn what is the corresponding keyword of `pass`, like we have in Python. My aim is: if result is successful, just move along, if not, there are two ways to handle that panic.

Comment: Maybe just leave the else branch out completely?

Comment: That is a way, and that is what I mean by "`if`s" in my question. But I want to know about a no-op in Rust, similar to pass, something that would do nothing if an if condition is true.

Comment: You can leave an empty block and the program will compile. `pass` in python is required since python is an indent-sensitive language, but Rust is not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Behold!

```rust
if predicate {
    do_things();
} else {
    // pass
}
```

Or even better

```rust
if predicate {
    do_things();
} // pass
```

Or as I’ve recently taken to calling it the implicit + pass system

```rust
if predicate {
    do_things();
}
```

In all seriousness there is no pass and no need for a pass in rust. As for why it exists in python, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886168/how-to-use-the-pass-statement)

Answer (score 12):

Python needs `pass` because it uses indentation-based blocks, so it requires *some* syntax to "do nothing". For example, this would be a syntax error in a Python program:

```py
# syntax error - function definition cannot be empty
def ignore(_doc):
    # do nothing

count = process_docs(docs, ignore)  # just count the docs
```

The `ignore` function has to contain a *block*, which in turn must contain at least one statement. We could insert a dummy statement like `None`, but Python provides `pass` which compiles to nothing and signals the intention (to do nothing) to the human reader.

This is not needed in Rust because Rust uses braces for blocks, so one can always create an empty block simply using `{}`:

```rust
// no error - empty blocks are fine
fn ignore(_doc: &Document) {
    // do nothing
}

let count = process_docs(docs, ignore);  // just count the docs
```

Of course, in both idiomatic Python and Rust, one would use a closure for something as simple as the above `ignore` function, but there are still situations where `pass` and empty blocks are genuinely useful.

Comment: but only on blocks that return () or have a branch that returns something right?

Comment: @matt Right. The response was addressing the question which explicitly asked for an equivalent to Python's `pass`. In that context returning nothing (`()` in Rust, `None` in Python) is implied.