# Python http error logging

Tags: python, http, logging, error-handling

following question

I do have a python script working and doing HTTP requests. 
Sometimes I get several errors like the http 400. Now I want to log those and interrupt the script from stop working.

```
 import logging

 date = .strftime().....

 try: 
        script X
 except:
        error = urllib2.HTTPError
        errorcode = error.code
        file = open ("error.txt",'r+')
        file.write("Error Code: %s, date \n", errorcode)
        file.close()
        pass
```

Is that right? Or did I something wrong. Should I use an If for the HTTP error?

Will this prevent the script from stopping while getting an error -> pass

Thank You!

Comment: Why cant you just try it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line saying:

```
error = urllib2.HTTPError
```

makes no sense in this context. It is saying `error` is the `urllib2.HTTPError` class. That class is used for raising exceptions, you are interested in catching exceptions.

Usually we write:

```
try: 
    #  http attempt
except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
    errorcode = error.code
```

This says the type of the exception you are handling, `urllib2.HTTPError`, and that is what type `error` will be, or any class object which inherits from `urllib2.HTTPError`.

It also means you won't handle any other kinds of exceptions. This is a good thing. Only deal with what you can handle and let everything else fly past you.

At the moment your `except` statement catches every possible exception type. You also throw away the information, so you don't really know what the exception was.

Writing to a file, use `with`. This makes sure the file is closed properly if there is an exception whilst writing to it. Don't use `file` as a variable name. You need to interpolate the string format using `%`:

```
    with open ("error.txt",'r+') as log:
        log.write("Error Code: %s, date \n" % errorcode)
```

Okay, code review over.

Comment: oh right, thank you, my bad. So I will log the error but still use 'pass' for 'going on'

Comment: You only need `pass` if the block would otherwise be empty. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528903/how-to-write-an-empty-indentation-block-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

Use python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/) library::::

```
try:
    res = requests.post(url, data, headers=headers, auth=auth)
    if res.status_code == 200 or res.status_code == 201:
        return 'SUCCESS', res.content
    else:
        return 'FAIL', res.status_code
except Exception as e:
    print "Http request failed... %s" % traceback.format_exc()
```

Comment: You should use [`raise_for_status`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes).

Comment: but your method is w/o a error logging. Only printing the error isn't my aim. Furthermore I used the urllib2 instead of request. Should I change it to the request method?

Comment: Don't recommend installing a library for a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to structure your code is to use error logging (a feature built into Python):

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('__name__')

fh = logging.FileHandler('errors.log')
logger.addHandler(fh)

try:
   # something
except urllib2.HttpError, e:
   logger.error(e)
```