# Primes function, return in function

Tags: python, primes

```
def primes_number(number = 5):
    for x in range(1, number):

        for y in range(2, x):

            if((number % x) == 0):

            else:
                print(y)

print(primes_number())
```

```
line 9
    else:
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Why program sees the problem here?
When i delete else: I have only "none" as output which is quite weird.

Comment: If you have nothing inside `if`, you must use `pass` inside the `if` body

Comment: Python doesn't allow empty blocks. Add a `pass` statement inside `if`. Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528903/how-to-write-an-empty-indentation-block-in-python

Comment: The main `print` does print what the method returns, and as the method have no `return` it shows None

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple mistakes in your code:

```
if((number % x) == 0):
```

We're finished with the `number` variable at this point, this should be `x % y`

```
for y in range(2, x):
    if((number % x) == 0):
    else:
```

This `else` belongs on the `for`, not the `if`.  I'll demonstrate below.

```
        print(y)
```

We should be printing `x` if success, not `y`, the divisor.

```
print(primes_number())
```

No need to print here as `primes_number()` doesn't return anything and you've done all the printing within the function itself.

Here's a working version with minimal modifications to your code:

```
def primes_number(number=30):
    for x in range(2, number):
        for y in range(2, int(x ** 0.5) + 1):
            if x % y == 0:
                break
        else:  # no break
            print(x)

primes_number()
```

I did throw in one optimization, only testing divisors up to the square root of the number.

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
%
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something under `if`. Python requires code there. You can use `pass` if you don't want to add anything there.

This will make your code look like this:

```
def primes_number(number = 5):
    for x in range(1, number):

        for y in range(2, x):

            if((number % x) == 0):
                pass
            else:
                print(y)

print(primes_number())
```

Answer (score 0):

here is cleaner version;
a) removed print of output of function since None is returned
b) track all primes in a primeDict (dictionary)...

```
def primes_number(number = 5):
    primesDict = {}
    for x in range(1, number):

        for y in range(2, x):

            if((number % x) != 0):
                if y in primesDict : continue
                primesDict[y] = x
                print(y)

print(primes_number(number=7))
```

output

```
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: I guessing from the context that this program is about **prime** numbers and **4** isn't prime and shouldn't be in `primeDict` nor printed.  Your output also includes a trailing `None`, not shown above.